# Convert factor vector to numeric while preserving variable decimal places

Tags: r

`as.numeric` seems to format all values to take the greatest number of decimal places found in the vector. Is there a way to return a numeric vector from a factor vector that conserves the number of decimal places that each value originally had?

```
vals <- factor(c('1', '1.1', '1.11', '1.111'))
as.numeric(as.character(vals))
# [1] 1.000 1.100 1.110 1.111 # every value has 3 decimal places
```

Desired output (as numeric vector, not factor!):

```
# [1] 1 1.1 1.11 1.111 # every value has conserved the original number of decimal places
```

Why do I want this?

Imaging a long dataframe with `value` and `measurement` variables. In the `measurement` column are two separate measurement categories (e.g., `weight`, `height`). The measurement categories may have their own units and number of significant figures. Therefore, if `weight` is significant to one decimal place, but `height` is significant to two decimal places, it would be inaccurate to list a `weight` value as `1.10`--it should be `1.1`.

Comment: All numeric values have the same number of decimal places in R according to the rules of floating point arithmetic. When printed to the screen, R tries to make them look pretty and have them all use the least number of decimal places while still allowing you to tell different values apart when possible. If you need to keep a particular visual representation of the number, then you should keep the string/factor version as well. Is there a reason you need to preserve formatting?

Comment: If you're working in the tidyverse, they will display close to your desired output by default if printed as a column in a tibble. e.g. `tibble(v)` prints them without any trailing 0s, but the last one is rounded to two decimals. If you run `options(pillar.sigfig = 4)` it won't round the last one when printing.

Comment: @MrFlick` Thanks for the response, please see edit for reasoning--the vector's values are grouped into different categories that have different significant figures, so it's not accurate to display trailing zeroes when they aren't there in the original data.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks, it looks like this is the way to go. Especially with `options()`. Appreciate it.

Comment: This isn't going to be easy in R. There is no native "decimal" data type to keep track of significant figures. Most people just round at the end when doing stats.